# How to generate csv response in elasticsearch?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch

As we know, the `rest apis` of **Elasticsearch** returns `json response`.But, I need `CSV responses` from those apis.

I am looking to similar feature to that is available in `Solr`.Solr provides `CSV response writer` using which, we can easily get responses in `csv form`.

How do I achieve this is Elasticsearch ?

**Note**: *I am not looking to just export all the contents of ElasticSearch cluster into csv format. I want to `query elasticsearch rest apis` and get responses in `csv format` instead of json.*

**UPDATE**

I have been trying to use `logstash` using the approach recommended by @Val in the answer.

Below is the contents of `logstash-plain.log`

```
    [2017-01-23T18:28:35,762][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-01-23T18:28:35,783][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-01-23T18:28:35,827][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Elasticsearch hosts=>["localhost:9200"], index=>"megacorp", query=>"_index:megacorp AND first_name:Jane", id=>"9a67b0421108afd201382b21693e2173243dd144-1", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON id=>"json_60457023-6344-4af7-a2c5-1e89d1fe08aa", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, size=>1000, scroll=>"1m", docinfo=>false, docinfo_target=>"@metadata", docinfo_fields=>["_index", "_type", "_id"], ssl=>false>
  Error: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}
[2017-01-23T18:28:35,881][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-01-23T18:28:36,838][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Elasticsearch hosts=>["localhost:9200"], index=>"megacorp", query=>"_index:megacorp AND first_name:Jane", id=>"9a67b0421108afd201382b21693e2173243dd144-1", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON id=>"json_60457023-6344-4af7-a2c5-1e89d1fe08aa", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, size=>1000, scroll=>"1m", docinfo=>false, docinfo_target=>"@metadata", docinfo_fields=>["_index", "_type", "_id"], ssl=>false>
  Error: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}
[2017-01-23T18:28:37,848][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Elasticsearch hosts=>["localhost:9200"], index=>"megacorp", query=>"_index:megacorp AND first_name:Jane", id=>"9a67b0421108afd201382b21693e2173243dd144-1", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON id=>"json_60457023-6344-4af7-a2c5-1e89d1fe08aa", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, size=>1000, scroll=>"1m", docinfo=>false, docinfo_target=>"@metadata", docinfo_fields=>["_index", "_type", "_id"], ssl=>false>
  Error: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}
[2017-01-23T18:28:38,865][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
```

Below is the contents of `elasticsearch.log`

```
    2017-01-23T19:06:38,633][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2017-01-23T19:06:38,751][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [TgbIozs] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda8)]], net usable_space [36.9gb], net total_space [139.6gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2017-01-23T19:06:38,752][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [TgbIozs] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-01-23T19:06:38,760][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [TgbIozs] derived from node ID [TgbIozsCR5WWSm_8iU-Rdw]; set [node.name] to override
[2017-01-23T19:06:38,761][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[5.1.2], pid[7239], build[c8c4c16/2017-01-11T20:18:39.146Z], OS[Linux/3.16.0-70-generic/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_77/25.77-b03]
[2017-01-23T19:06:39,764][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [TgbIozs] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-01-23T19:06:39,765][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [TgbIozs] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-01-23T19:06:39,765][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [TgbIozs] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-01-23T19:06:39,765][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [TgbIozs] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-01-23T19:06:39,765][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [TgbIozs] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-01-23T19:06:39,766][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [TgbIozs] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-01-23T19:06:39,766][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [TgbIozs] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-01-23T19:06:39,766][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [TgbIozs] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-01-23T19:06:39,766][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [TgbIozs] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-01-23T19:06:39,766][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [TgbIozs] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-01-23T19:06:39,767][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [TgbIozs] no plugins loaded
[2017-01-23T19:06:42,342][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2017-01-23T19:06:42,342][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [TgbIozs] starting ...
[2017-01-23T19:06:42,595][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [TgbIozs] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2017-01-23T19:06:42,610][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [TgbIozs] max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
[2017-01-23T19:06:42,611][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [TgbIozs] max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2017-01-23T19:06:45,816][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [TgbIozs] new_master {TgbIozs}{TgbIozsCR5WWSm_8iU-Rdw}{U2MjduBXTcOYx50aXsY-CQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2017-01-23T19:06:45,860][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [TgbIozs] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2017-01-23T19:06:45,861][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [TgbIozs] started
[2017-01-23T19:06:46,211][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [TgbIozs] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2017-01-23T19:06:47,046][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [TgbIozs] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[megacorp][0]] ...]).
[2017-01-23T19:07:35,357][DEBUG][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [TgbIozs] processing [cluster_update_settings]: took [18ms] done applying updated cluster_state (version: 7, uuid: Wc1Xm4H5SSOcJ6lIM--Stg)
[2017-01-23T19:07:35,357][DEBUG][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [TgbIozs] processing [reroute_after_cluster_update_settings]: execute
[2017-01-23T19:07:35,363][DEBUG][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [TgbIozs] processing [reroute_after_cluster_update_settings]: took [4ms] no change in cluster_state
[2017-01-23T19:07:35,370][DEBUG][i.n.h.c.c.ZlibCodecFactory] -Dio.netty.noJdkZlibDecoder: false
[2017-01-23T19:07:35,372][DEBUG][i.n.h.c.c.ZlibCodecFactory] -Dio.netty.noJdkZlibEncoder: false
[2017-01-23T19:07:35,674][DEBUG][r.suppressed             ] path: /megacorp/_search, params: {size=1000, scroll=1m, index=megacorp}
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchParseException: Failed to derive xcontent
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.xContent(XContentFactory.java:239) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.search.RestSearchAction.parseSearchRequest(RestSearchAction.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.search.RestSearchAction.prepareRequest(RestSearchAction.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:66) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.executeHandler(RestController.java:243) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:200) [elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer.dispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:113) [elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(Netty4HttpServerTransport.java:507) [transport-netty4-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:69) [transport-netty4-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.channelRead(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:66) [transport-netty4-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:536) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:490) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873) [netty-common-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_77]
```

A response generated in the `logstash console`:

Command Entered: `logstash_csv.sh "first_name:Jane" "first_name,last_name"`

```
STARTING logstash_csv script......
Sending Logstash's logs to /home/sagarhp/installations/logstash-5.1.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-01-23T19:49:25,103][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-01-23T19:49:25,131][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-01-23T19:49:25,239][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-01-23T19:49:25,386][INFO ][logstash.outputs.csv     ] Opening file {:path=>"/home/sagarhp/mybin/test.csv"}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-01-23T14:04:25.361Z,
         "about" => "I like to collect rock albums",
      "@version" => "1",
     "last_name" => "Smith",
     "interests" => [
        [0] "music"
    ],
    "first_name" => "Jane",
           "age" => 32
}
[2017-01-23T19:49:28,159][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

**UPDATE**: replaced `logstash 5.1.2 with 2.4.1`. The elasticsearch version is 5.1.2 as before.

Below is the contents of `elasticsearch.log`:

```
[2017-01-24T11:35:18,909][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2017-01-24T11:35:19,101][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [T7CEo0J] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda8)]], net usable_space [35.7gb], net total_space [139.6gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2017-01-24T11:35:19,102][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [T7CEo0J] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-01-24T11:35:19,111][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [T7CEo0J] derived from node ID [T7CEo0J8SOqX13kNEAPAvg]; set [node.name] to override
[2017-01-24T11:35:19,122][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[5.1.2], pid[8973], build[c8c4c16/2017-01-11T20:18:39.146Z], OS[Linux/3.16.0-70-generic/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_77/25.77-b03]
[2017-01-24T11:35:20,209][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [T7CEo0J] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-01-24T11:35:20,209][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [T7CEo0J] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-01-24T11:35:20,209][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [T7CEo0J] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-01-24T11:35:20,210][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [T7CEo0J] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-01-24T11:35:20,210][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [T7CEo0J] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-01-24T11:35:20,210][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [T7CEo0J] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-01-24T11:35:20,210][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [T7CEo0J] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-01-24T11:35:20,210][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [T7CEo0J] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-01-24T11:35:20,210][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [T7CEo0J] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-01-24T11:35:20,211][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [T7CEo0J] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-01-24T11:35:20,211][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [T7CEo0J] no plugins loaded
[2017-01-24T11:35:22,810][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2017-01-24T11:35:22,811][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [T7CEo0J] starting ...
[2017-01-24T11:35:23,039][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [T7CEo0J] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2017-01-24T11:35:23,054][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [T7CEo0J] max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
[2017-01-24T11:35:23,055][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [T7CEo0J] max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2017-01-24T11:35:26,258][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [T7CEo0J] new_master {T7CEo0J}{T7CEo0J8SOqX13kNEAPAvg}{rOR6BRP9S6CqXOChtboGLA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2017-01-24T11:35:26,319][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [T7CEo0J] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2017-01-24T11:35:26,320][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [T7CEo0J] started
[2017-01-24T11:35:26,616][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [T7CEo0J] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2017-01-24T11:35:27,494][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [T7CEo0J] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[megacorp][1]] ...]).
[2017-01-24T11:35:55,245][DEBUG][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [T7CEo0J] processing [cluster_update_settings]: took [31ms] done applying updated cluster_state (version: 7, uuid: RYMpMgAlT1yXJu8Wkdf-pg)
[2017-01-24T11:35:55,245][DEBUG][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [T7CEo0J] processing [reroute_after_cluster_update_settings]: execute
[2017-01-24T11:35:55,253][DEBUG][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [T7CEo0J] processing [reroute_after_cluster_update_settings]: took [7ms] no change in cluster_state
[2017-01-24T11:36:12,203][DEBUG][r.suppressed             ] path: /megacorp/_search, params: {size=1000, scroll=1m, index=megacorp, search_type=scan}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No search type for [scan]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchType.fromString(SearchType.java:107) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.search.RestSearchAction.parseSearchRequest(RestSearchAction.java:114) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.search.RestSearchAction.prepareRequest(RestSearchAction.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:66) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.executeHandler(RestController.java:243) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:200) [elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer.dispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:113) [elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(Netty4HttpServerTransport.java:507) [transport-netty4-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:69) [transport-netty4-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.channelRead(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:66) [transport-netty4-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267) [netty-codec-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:536) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:490) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450) [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873) [netty-common-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_77]
```

Below is what i got in the `logstash console` :

```
STARTING logstash_csv script......
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 4
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Elasticsearch hosts=>["localhost:9200"], index=>"megacorp", query=>"{\"query\":{\"query_string\": {\"query\": \"first_name:Jane\"}}}", codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON charset=>"UTF-8">, scan=>true, size=>1000, scroll=>"1m", docinfo=>false, docinfo_target=>"@metadata", docinfo_fields=>["_index", "_type", "_id"], ssl=>false>
  Error: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No search type for [scan]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No search type for [scan]"},"status":400} {:level=>:error}
Pipeline main started
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Elasticsearch hosts=>["localhost:9200"], index=>"megacorp", query=>"{\"query\":{\"query_string\": {\"query\": \"first_name:Jane\"}}}", codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON charset=>"UTF-8">, scan=>true, size=>1000, scroll=>"1m", docinfo=>false, docinfo_target=>"@metadata", docinfo_fields=>["_index", "_type", "_id"], ssl=>false>
  Error: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No search type for [scan]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No search type for [scan]"},"status":400} {:level=>:error}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're open to use Logstash, then you can very easily do this with an [`elasticsearch` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) making the query and then a [`csv` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-csv.html) for dumping the data into a CSV file. It'd look like this:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "your_index"
    query => '{"query": {"match_all": {}}}'
  }
}
output {
  csv {
    fields => ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
    path => "/path/to/file.csv"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to invoke this dynamically, you could generate this logstash configuration dynamically based on a query that you'd give as input to the shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$LOGSTASH_HOME" ]; then
    echo "WARNING: The LOGSTASH_HOME environment variable is not set!"
    exit 0
fi

LS_CONF="input {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => [\"localhost:9200\"]
     index => 'megacorp'
     query => '{\"query\":{\"query_string\": {\"query\": \"$1\"}}}'
   }
}
output {
   csv {
     fields => [$2]
     path => \"/path/to/file.csv\"
   }
}"

$LOGSTASH_HOME/bin/logstash -e "$LS_CONF"
```

Then you can invoke that script with the query `my_field:123456` like this

```
./es_to_csv.sh "my_field:123456" "field1,field2,field3"
```

This will have the same effect as calling `{{elasticUrl}}/_search?q=my_field:123456` and produce a CSV file with the columns `field1,field2,field3`

Comment: thank you for your response. As, far as I understand, I will have to provide this in Logstash configuration and run the logstash. So, if I provide custom query to elasticsearch such as: `{{elasticUrl}}/_search?q=....` ,
all the documents satisfying the given query will be exported to file.csv. Am I understanding this correctly ? I am asking to make sure that the documents will be filtered according to the query and then only written to csv.

Comment: Yes, the query part will look like this `query => '...'` where `...` is whatever you'd put behind the `q=...` parameter in your URL

Comment: There's no request URL when running logstash, you simply run `bin/logstash -f yourconfig.conf`

Comment: Okay thanks. And what about the `fields` configuration ? Do, they also respect what we pass in the URL ? Or, are they static and will not change ?

Comment: See my comment above

Comment: So,do I have to run logstash, everytime whenever I have to generate CSV files ? Because, requirement changes everytime. Does that mean, I will have to modify the `logstash config file` everytime I have a different query and different fields to write ? Please help me understand this.

Comment: What we could do is to put that Logstash config in a shell script that you can invoke with a specific query each time

Comment: See my updated answer above, no need to change anything, simply invoke the script with a new query each time

Comment: Okay. And how can I dynamically control what fields are written to csv ? I see that script handles the query param. It would be helpful if we could also pass fields.

Comment: I created a similar script as suggested. To test, I have created an index `megacorp` with an index type `employee`. So, I need to write those employees to csv file whose `first_name:Jane`. And I want to write fields `first_name, last_name` to the csv file. I ran the script using command: `logstash_csv.sh "first_name:Jane" "first_name,last_name"`. But I am continuously getting the error:   **Error: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}**

Comment: update your question with your `logstash_csv.sh` file, please. Or is it exactly the same as mine (you said "similar")?

Comment: Only the csv file path i.e `output.csv.path` is changed. Everything else is same. And do I have to specify index name as well  ?Actually, I need to filter on the `megacorp` index with index_type `employee` . So I was wondering if I have to specify `index name` and `index type` as well.

Comment: Ok, yes, you probably need to add `index => "megacorp"` in your `elasticsearch` input. See my updated answer

Comment: Updated the script with index settings. But, still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try to use this query instead: `"_index:megacorp AND first_name:Jane"`. Maybe you have an old version of Logstash which doesn't support the `index` parameter.

Comment: Tried using that query. It didn't work. I am using `ElasticSearch 5.1.2` and `logstash 5.1.2`.

Comment: Did you get the same error? Could you provide the full error you get as an update to your question? Make sure to get it from the ES server logs.

Comment: I am not getting error on the ES server .The error I mentioned is appearing in the `logstash shell`. And the error is same which I mentioned earlier. I have shared the contents of `logstash-plain.log` in my question.

Comment: The error you're getting is coming from ES, Logstash is just relaying it, please find the related error in the ES server logs.

Comment: Okay. I have added the contents of `ES_HOME/logs/elasticsearch.log`.

Comment: According to the timestamps, the errors in Logstash appear before the ES logs you've shared.

Comment: Yes, I had cleaned the `elasticsearch.log` to see recent changes.So, just now I cleaned the `logstash-plain.log` again and again ran the script. I have updated the contents of `logstash-plain.log` which was generated just now. The contents are same as before.

Comment: But now I also need to see the latest ES logs you get :-)

Comment: The `elasticsearch.log` hasn't changed at all. No data has been added in this log file. I dont know why. It just the same as I have added in the question.

Comment: Honestly, unless you're hitting another ES server from Logstash, I don't see how this is possible since Logstash shows the error raised by ES, that error must be present in the ES logs.

Comment: I have updated my `elasticsearch.log`. Actually, I had to set my `LOG LEVEL` to `DEBUG` to see those hidden exceptions :)

Comment: Ok, can you replace the query line in the script with this `query => '{\"query\":{\"query_string\": {\"query\": \"$1\"}}}'` ?

Comment: Replaced the query. Ran the script as:  `logstash_csv.sh "first_name:Jane" "first_name,last_name"` . The `logstash` ran successfully. But, the contents of csv file is not as expected. It includes this data: ***2017-01-23T13:49:04.684Z %{host} %{message}***

Comment: Can you add this after the `csv` output: `stdout {codec => rubydebug}` What do you see in the logstash output?

Comment: After adding that line, I can see the `printed data json` including all fields  which satisfies my query. The json includes two additional fields also: `"@timestamp" =>2017-01-23T14:04:25.361Z,"@version" => "1"`. And I can see that only the value of time stamp field is being written in the csv file.

Comment: Can you update your question with one event you see printed out in the logstash log?

Comment: Yes, I have done the necessary update on the question.

Comment: Hmm, maybe there's an issue in the script, can you try to run the script like this instead: `logstash_csv.sh "first_name:Jane" '"first_name","last_name"'`

Comment: Got the same response as before.

Comment: Oh I know... You're bumping in [this issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-csv/issues/10) which is not yet resolved in logstash 5.1.2. You can try to run Logstash 2.4 instead and this will work out just fine.

Comment: I used `Logstash 2.4`. I used the same `elasticsearch 5.1.2`. I got different type of error this time. I have `updated the question with logs`.

Comment: Yeah, obviously Logstash 2.4 doesn't play well with ES 5... Well, you could try with ES 2.4, but if that's not be feasible for you. you'll need to wait until that Logstash 5 `csv` output is fixed.

Comment: You can try a last thing, i.e. set `scan => false` in your `elasticsearch` input, that might do the trick

Comment: Yes, It worked. Thanks a lot. And one more thong i want to ask is , can i aslo specify the `index_type` in the config ? I mean I will have multiple index_types within an index. For eg: in this case, my index is `megacorp` and `index type` is `employee`.So, I could also have other index types within megacorp such as: supervisors, customers etc.

Comment: Yes, that's called `document_type => 'supervisors'` which you need to add to the `elasticsearch` input

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat difficult, because inherently - JSON is a hierarchical data structure, and CSV is not.

There isn't a trivial way of reducing one to the other as a result - anything you do will be custom.

However you can do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP;
use JSON;

my $url =
  'http://localhost:9200/index-name/path/AVm7dsU_mwKGPn0NRXkK';

my $agent    = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $agent->get($url);

if ( $response->code ) {
   my $json = from_json( $response->content );
   my @fields = sort keys %{ $json->{_source} };

   #column headings
   print join ",", @fields, "\n";
   #column values
   print join ",", @{ $json->{_source} }{@fields}, "\n";
}
```

It's a bit crude, and assumes that with `_source` there's a flat key-value relationship. With multiple records you'd need to wrap it in a loop to print multiple - this is just an example with a single document.

It would be better - if at all possible - to change whatever is wanting the CSV, to handle a multi dimensional data format in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, i don't only have flat key-value relationship. I have `json data in nested form`.I am using `ElasticSearch` currently. Before, I was using `Apache Solr` where I was capable of generating csv data from nested json. Solr stored the deeply nested json in flattened form and could return csv simply by specifying `wt=csv` in the request param. Like Solr, ElasticSearch too is built on top of `Lucene`. And , I was hoping that ElasticSearch too was capable of producing csv responses similarly.

Comment: Well, the above will allow you to flatten out the json, but you'll have to decide how you want to do it. e.g. if it's an array, do you want to concat the keys into a single field? Or unroll the data structure so it's multiple rows (and bear in mind - that means you'd possibly have a lot of rows if you've many multi-value fields).