# How to export elasticsearch raw data to csv

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5, kibana-6

I recently started using elasticsearch database and kibana 5.6.9. I was able to export the visualization data to csv using kibana, but not the raw data.

Am in search of a method, where I should be able to export the raw data from Elasticsearch to a CSV file. Can I get some help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Often you'll end up writing custom code - but this might help you - https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763752/how-to-generate-csv-response-in-elasticsearch/41763802#41763802 (no need for custom coding, simply use Logstash)

Answer (score 0):

This is the possible way to export data from ElasticSearch to CSV:

1. Make a snapshot (if doesn’t exist yet)
2. Use esbackupexporter to convert the snapshot to zipped JSON files.
3. Use lodpad to search (filter) the events you really need from these zipped JSONs.
4. Then export to csv from logpad.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv.

You could do something like the below:

```
es2csv -a username:password -u http://<your_es_host>:9200 -i your_index_name -o csv_file.csv -r -q '{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}'
```